# Django, use complex Q object query string on a record

Tags: django

We have a Q object string similar to

```
filter_string1 = {'question__startswith':'Who'}
filter_string2 = {'question__startswith':'What'}
filter = Q(**filter_string1) | Q(**filter_string2) && Q(**filter_string1)
```

This can be used as :

```
Models.objects.filter(filter)
```

Can we use this filter to check if a **certain record** (a single record, instance of a model) satisfy above conditions.

Edited to clear question

if the filter looks something like this:

```
filter = Q(question__startswith = "Who") | Q(question__startswith = "What")
```

I want to get below result without actually writing it again. Using just filter and the object.

```
object = Model.objects.filter(id = 1)
if object.question.startswith("Who")  or object.question.startswith("What")
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Note: object may not be saved to database yet.

Comment: What if there are two or more records that satisfy this?

Comment: We actually have the object we want to compare at hand. Not a queryset.

Comment: bro can you please little bit explain the use case I am not able to get what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have a query string using Q object, I use it to filter querysets, Whereas, sometimes I need to check if a certain record match these criterias. I dont want to rewrite things and use same queryset filters to check.